# Having trouble with while loop in my number guessing game

Tags: javascript, html, loops, for-loop, while-loop

So, I'm having trouble starting a while or for loop to create a turn count, starting at 6, to allow the user who is guessing the number only 6 turns before he loses and gives a message stating he loses with the number which was supposed to be guessed. The turn count will count down to 0 one by one each time he inputs a guess into the textbox. I am confused as to where I would create the while loop, and where would I place the while loop. Is there multiple ways to create this action?

Thank you!

```
    //creating the guessing game function using if and else if statements
var guessGame = function(){
    var guess = document.getElementById("guessTextbox").value;
    var guessOutput = document.getElementById("gameStatus");

    //if guessed number is equal to the random number, winning display message is shown
    if (guess == guessNum){
        guessOutput.value = guessOutput.value + "You've guessed correctly! The correct number was: " + guessNum;
    }
    //else if statement for guesses not in the 1-100 range displaying error/incorrect message
    else if (guess > 100 || guess < 1){
        guessOutput.value = guessOutput.value + "Incorrect number range!";
    }
    else if (guess > guessNum){
        guessOutput.value = guessOutput.value + "The guess is too high!";
    }
    else if (guess < guessNum){
        guessOutput.value = guessOutput.value + "The guess is too low!";
    }
    //else if guess is NOT a number, displays message
    else if (isNaN(guess)){
        guessOutput.value = guessOutput.value + "Input value is not a number!";
    }
};
```

Comment: `guessOutput` is a DOM element, which unless it's an input element, does not have a `value` property. What does your HTML look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of achieving that goal. I've left some comments to help you navigate. Let me know if I can clarify anything.

```
// When initialized, guessGame returns a function that allows
// 6 guesses and then reveals the random number.
function guessGame() {

    // Start with 6 turns.
    this.turns = 6;

    // Generate random number guessNum s.t. 1 < guessNum < 100
    this.guessNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 2)) + 2;

    return function() {
      var guessOutput = document.getElementById("gameStatus");

      // If no turns left, output the message and return.
      if (this.turns === 0) {
        guessOutput.value = guessOutput.value + "You've ran out of turns! The correct number was: " + this.guessNum;
        return;
      }

      // Otherwise, match the next guess against guessNum.
      var guess = parseInt(document.getElementById("guessTextbox").value, 10);

      // If equal, display the winning message
      if (guess === this.guessNum){
          guessOutput.value = guessOutput.value + "You've guessed correctly! The correct number was: " + this.guessNum;
      }
      // If not in range, display error message
      // Advice: might want to move this before the equality check.
      else if (guess > 100 || guess < 1){
          guessOutput.value = guessOutput.value + "Incorrect number range!";
      }
      // If greater than, ...
      else if (guess > this.guessNum){
          guessOutput.value = guessOutput.value + "The guess is too high!";
      }
      // If less than, ...
      else if (guess < this.guessNum){
          guessOutput.value = guessOutput.value + "The guess is too low!";
          }
      // If not a number, display error.
      // Advice: might want to move this to the top of the checks.
      else if (isNaN(guess)){
          guessOutput.value = guessOutput.value + "Input value is not a number!";
      }

      // Decrement the number of turns.
      this.turns -= 1;

    // This helps the embedded function locate the random number.
    }.bind(this);
}
```

**Usage.**

```
// Initialize the game
// (Suppose the random number is 30)
var game = new guessGame();

// Enter 21 in guessTextbox
game(); // => "The guess is too low!"

// Enter 22 in guessTextbox
game(); // => "The guess is too low!"

// Enter 23 in guessTextbox
game(); // => "The guess is too low!"

// Enter 24 in guessTextbox
game(); // => "The guess is too low!"

// Enter 50 in guessTextbox
game(); // => "The guess is too high!"

// Enter 49 in guessTextbox
game(); // => "The guess is too high!"

// Enter 48 in guessTextbox
game(); // => "You've ran out of turns! The correct number was: 30"

// Enter 47 in guessTextbox
game();  // => "You've ran out of turns! The correct number was: 30"
```

You get the idea.

Comment: What's the "this" do?

Comment: @Brandon We've defined `guessGame` as an object. `turns`and `guessNum` are its properties. In order for the returned function to be able to refer to those properties, the returned function must know how to find them. By binding the `this` that owns those properties to the function we're allowing it to share those properties of the parent function. That's the purpose that `this` serves here. It has many applications, of course. When you get a chance, read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_an_object_method).

Comment: Ah, yeah having just sorta learned how objects and properties work made this confusing, but helps a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should put it where you are calling the function and lower the guesses with every call. And put your message that he's guesses are o er under the cycle. But I don't know where you are going to call it. If you are calling it on a click event you don't need a loop. Just put a var guesses =5; for instance on page loading and decrease it in your function. Then check if it is 0 at the end of your function.

Answer (score 0):

The while loop in this case acts as your game loop. Non-zero numbers evaluate truthy, so the while loop will run until guessesRemaining equals something falsy (0 in this case). I did not penalize the player for guessing out of range, and non-integer guesses, but that is an easy change if that's something you want. I made the user input a prompt() for simplicity in this example. As a side note, you would typically check for valid values FIRST (ie NaN, null, etc) before testing for the correct answer. You may also want to parseInt() on the user input.

```
        //creating the guessing game function using if and else if statements
function guessGame(){
    var guessesRemaining = 6,
        guessNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
        guessOutput = document.getElementById("gameStatus");

    while(guessesRemaining){ // non-zero numbers are truthy
        var guess = prompt();
        //if guessed number is equal to the random number, winning display message is shown
        if (guess == guessNum){
            guessOutput.value = guessOutput.value + " You've guessed correctly! The correct number was: " + guessNum;
            guessesRemaining = 0; // No more guesses needed!!!
        }
        else if (isNaN(guess)){
            guessOutput.value = guessOutput.value + " Input value is not a number!";
            // decriment here if penalty for invalid guess is incurred
        }
        //else if statement for guesses not in the 1-100 range displaying error/incorrect message
        else if (guess > 100 || guess < 1){
            guessOutput.value = guessOutput.value + " Incorrect number range!";
            // decriment here if penalty for invalid guess is incurred
        }
        else if (guess > guessNum){
            guessOutput.value = guessOutput.value + " The guess is too high!";
            guessesRemaining--; // decriment remaining guesses
        }
        else if (guess < guessNum){
            guessOutput.value = guessOutput.value + " The guess is too low!";
            guessesRemaining--; // decriment remaining guesses
        }
    }
};
```

Let me know if you need clarity on anything.